# Terraform AWS CMK script throws a Not Authorized Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create a CMK for my SQS queue to allow encrypted SNS messages to be sent to my encrypted queue. After I create the cmk, I will set it to the "kms_master_key_id" in my queue.

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "mycmk" {
  description             = "KMS Key"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10

  policy = <<POLICY
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [{
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": [
            "kms:GenerateDataKey",
            "kms:Decrypt"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
       }]
}
POLICY
}
```

This is throwing an error:
`my_role_arn is not authorized to perform: kms:CreateKey on resource: *`
I've double checked to make sure that action is allowed and it is.
Do I need to update the 'resource' in the policy? If so to what?

The role I am using to run this has these permissions:

```
 Effect = "Allow"
          Action = [
            "kms:CreateAlias",
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:CreateKey",
            "kms:DeleteAlias",
            "kms:DisableKey",
            "kms:EnableKey",
            "kms:PutKeyPolicy",
            "kms:RevokeGrant",
            "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
            "kms:TagResource",
            "kms:UntagResource",
            "kms:UpdateAlias",
            "kms:UpdateKeyDescription"
          ]
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:kms:${local.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:key/*",
            "arn:aws:kms:${local.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:alias/*"
          ]
```

Comment: The user you use to run the terraform is not authorized to create a key, that is unrelated to the policy shown. What user / role are you using and what permissions do they have?

Comment: I updated the question with the permissions I have

Comment: I think you need CreateKey on the resource * instead of a specific one.

Comment: Sorry, still learning AWS. could you elaborate on your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone else suggested, it looks like the credentials you use to run Terraform don't have the right permissions.

`CreateKey` explicitly only works with the "*" resource, so change the policy to this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "key_Access" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "kms:CreateAlias",      
      "kms:CreateGrant",
      "kms:DeleteAlias",
      "kms:DisableKey",
      "kms:EnableKey",
      "kms:PutKeyPolicy",
      "kms:RevokeGrant",
      "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
      "kms:TagResource",
      "kms:UntagResource",
      "kms:UpdateAlias",
      "kms:UpdateKeyDescription"
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:kms:${local.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:key/*",
      "arn:aws:kms:${local.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:alias/*"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = ["kms:CreateKey"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

With that being said, maybe don't make your own policy. Just assign the existing policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser` to the role. That gives the following permissions:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateAlias",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "kms:DeleteAlias",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:GenerateRandom",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "iam:ListGroups",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```